# Dúvida Exercício - Acadêmico

Tags: c

Minha dúvida é na letra B, é solicitado que eu faça a conta entre os 20 primeiros termos, como eu faço essa limitação de 20 termos da conta? Eu até coloquei já a fórmula no *for (i = 5, j = 3; ;i += 2, j += 2)* 
Mas falta introduzir o intervalo do i e j que é minha dúvida. Obrigado

Segue questão: 
Calcular o somatório das seguintes séries :
a) S = 1 + 1/3 + 1/5 + 1/7 + ............+ 1/99

**b) S = 1 – 1/3 + 1/5 – 1/7 + .............para os primeiros 20 termos**

```
int i, j;
double soma = 1, result = 1;
printf ("Somatorio dos termos: S = 1 + 1/3 + 1/5 + 1/7 + ............+ 1/99 \n");
for (i = 3; i <= 99; i += 2) {
    soma = soma + (1.0/i);
}
printf ("a) Soma = %lf \n\n", soma);

for (i = 5, j = 3; ;i += 2, j += 2) {
    result = result - 1.0/j + 1.0/i; 
}
printf ("b) Resultado = %lf \n\n", result);

system ("PAUSE");
```

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas galera, eu consegui fazer de outra forma, provavelmente não ficou do jeito "correto" mas o resultado da o mesmo. 

  for (k = 5, j = 3, cont = 0; cont < 20 ; k += 2, j += 2, cont++) {
   result = result - 1.0/j + 1.0/k; 
  }

Pelo menos é a forma que eu consigo pensar sem bugar a mente

Answer (score 0):

Tente utilizar o comando de repetição da forma correta. Por ex.:

```
int i, j;
double soma = 0, result = 1, sinal=1;
printf ("Somatorio dos termos: S = 1 + 1/3 + 1/5 + 1/7 + ............+ 1/99 \n");
for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    soma +=  1.0/(float) 2*i-1;
}
printf ("a) Soma = %lf \n\n", soma);

for (i = 1; i<=20; i++) {
   result += (float) sinal / (float) 2*i-1; 
    sinal =-sinal;
}
printf ("b) Resultado = %lf \n\n", result);
```

Comment: Buguei a mente agora

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int count = 0, k = 0; count < 20; count++){
if(count == 0){
    resultado += 1;
}else{
    if(count % 2 == 0){
        resultado -= (float) 1/(3 + k);
        k += 2;
    }else{
        resultado += (float) 1/(3 + k);
        k += 2;
    }

}

count += 1;
}
```

Comment: Eu traria uma explicação juntamente com o código para facilitar o entendimento de sua resposta.

Comment: Vlww, vou fazer isso na próxima visto que o cara já conseguiu resolver.